Is it possible to cancel an on-going quest in Hogwarts Legacy?
I'm currently busy with a quest where Sebastian Sallow is taking me to Hogsmeade to get school supplies, but for some reason, my game keeps crashing when I enter Hogsmeade or shortly after I enter Hogsmeade.
I've tweaked lots of settings and I can't get it to stop crashing.
So I'd like to quit/stop the existing quest and try to see if I'm able to visit Hogsmeade outside of the quest
The problem is that with my latest save, I am already on the quest on my way to Hogsmeade with Sebastian.
The specific quest I am on is the "WELCOME TO HOGSMEADE" quest:

So ideally I'd just like to cancel the existing quest. Is this possible?

@pinckerman WELCOME TO HOGSMEADE

A couple of Reddit users wrote that "updating video card drivers fixed the crashes for me", so give this a try.

Have you changed any graphical settings, perhaps?

@pinckerman Yes. I've tried every possible graphic setting there is. Nothing helps. The game keeps crashing in Hogsmeade. I've tried various different combinations of graphics. I've actually been tweaking and trying to get past this mission for the past 4 hours and I tried for 2 hours yesterday as well. Nothing helps.

Are you using any mod?

@pinckerman No. Just base vanilla game.

This game is bugged as f..., so many people complain about crashes. Have you tried playing in windowed mode?

@pinckerman No I have not tried that. I will try it quickly.

@pinckerman Okay. So I've changed a setting and now my game doesn't open at all . It crashes as soon as I open the game.

@pinckerman I just kept opening the game and after the 30th try, it finally didn't crash. I haven't tried the windowed mode yet, but I managed to actually enter Hogsmeade and enter the first shop. So I have a save within Hogsmeade now. I'd still like to know how to cancel or exit a quest though if it's possible.

@pinckerman Okay. I've managed to get a lot further with windowed mode, but it still crashes. Thanks for the windowed mode hint. I'm going to keep it on windowed mode. Seems more stable on windowed mode.

Depending on the quest, you may find the option to abandon the quest.
You have to open your Field Guide menu, enter your Quests, and pick the one you want to restart. From here, you’ll see an “Abandon Quest” option at the bottom of your screen:

Unfortunataly, you won’t find this option on every quest.
